# React native method not a recognized objective C method

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to create bridge from native module to react native. I have tried all errors and solutions related to the same subject with no luck to get it running

Following is my swift code

```
import Foundation

@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject {
    
    let mySdk = MySdkBuilder.build()
    
    @objc func renderForm(_ intentId: String,
                          intentType: String,
                          withResolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                          withRejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {

        let rootViewController: UIViewController?

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene)?.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController
        } else {
            rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController
        }

        mySdk.renderForm(
            on: rootViewController,
            intentId: intentId,
            intentType: intentType
        ) { details in
            do {
                resolve(details)
            } catch {
                let error = NSError(domain: "MyDomain", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
                reject("1000", "Error message", error)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

```
#import "MyModule.h"

@implementation MyModule
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(renderForm:(NSString *)intentId
                  intentType:(NSString *)intentType
                  withResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  withRejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)


// Don't compile this code when we build for the old architecture.
#ifdef RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:
    (const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params
{
    return std::make_shared<facebook::react::NativeMyModuleSpecJSI>(params);
}
#endif

@end
```

and here is my .h file

```
#ifdef RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
#import "RNMyModuleSpec.h"

@interface MyModule : NSObject <NativeMyModuleSpec>
#else
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface MyModule : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
#endif

@end
```

But I got the following error when tried to run the app

```
Exception 'renderForm:intentType:withResolver:withRejecter: is not a recognized Objective-C method.' was thrown while invoking renderForm on target MyModule with params (
    ZOkYjmZ,
    Payment,
    46,
    47
)
```

I tried to change the order of the parameters and other solutions with no luck, any advice?